# Filtering with EF Core through multiple nested object relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have a new requirement to filter reports return from a query based on what amounts to a blacklist.

So originally I had this query which brings back all the pertinent information required and gets a list of reports associated to that particular user.

```
var reports = from r in Context.Reports
                          join ax in Context.AuthorizationXref on r.Id equals ax.ReportId
                          join g in Context.Groups on ax.GroupId equals g.Id
                          join ugx in Context.UsersGroupsXref on g.Id equals ugx.GroupId
                          where ugx.UserId == id
                          select r;
```

AuthorizationXref has ReportID and GroupId.

```
public partial class AuthorizationXref
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }

        public virtual Groups Group { get; set; }
        public virtual Reports Report { get; set; }
    }

public partial class Groups
    {
        public Groups()
        {
            AuthorizationXref = new HashSet<AuthorizationXref>();
            UsersGroupsXref = new HashSet<UsersGroupsXref>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AuthorizationXref> AuthorizationXref { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UsersGroupsXref> UsersGroupsXref { get; set; }
    }
```

User many to many Groups many to many Reports (the many to many is done through the XREFs).

While in here I have benched it at 700ms which seems really slow and I realize I am doing at least 4 hits to the DB so I tried to do this which amounted to the same data more or less but ~7 times faster:

```
    var repo = context.Reports
        .Include(x => x.AuthorizationXref)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Group)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.UsersGroupsXref)
        .ToList();
```

This benched at about 100ms but doesn't do any filtering on userId. These benchmarks are in Dev and will only worsen as we get into the higher environments where more and more reports are added to users. I know that using Selects is more efficient but I can't find examples of complex nested many-to-many selects on entities.

I can get about this far but don't know where to put the additional steps to drill deeper into the object.

```
var asdf = repo.Where(x=>x.AuthorizationXref.Any(y=>y.ReportId==x.Id));
```

End Goal is I need a list of Reports by userId removing those reports that appear by ID on another table. So there is a table called UserReportFilter and it has ReportId and UserId, any reports in that table should not appear in my end result.

As a side note if anyone can point me in the direction of a tutorial (preferably one that doesn't assume the reader knows absolutely everything) on how to use the Expressions I would appreciate it. I ran across [this article](https://benjii.me/2018/01/expression-projection-magic-entity-framework-core/) and it would seem like a powerful thing to learn for things like this, however I will need a bit more meat in the explanation. I understand the concept and I have used basic Func returns for queries but nothing that extensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have relation between Reports and UserReportFilter tables since you have ReportId in UserReportFilter table. Below expression should work,

```
var reports = context.Reports
    .Include(x => x.AuthorizationXref)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.Group)
    .ThenInclude(x => x.UsersGroupsXref)
    .Include(x => x.UserReportFilters)
    .Where(x => x.AuthorizationXref.Any(y => y.Group.UsersGroupsXref.Any(z => z.UserId==id))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't get Group from AuthorizationXref in the intellisense because it is a collection... I should have been more clear I guess.

Comment: can you share your AuthorizationXref.cs class as well? you should be able to get it, if it's a collection

Comment: I have added one of the classes which is pretty much the same for the other. This is my first major foray into EF and Core for that matter. Having numerous nested collections was never anything I needed to do and a sproc is usually the goto for this sort of thing, but I have tried not to resort to it in this project.

Comment: Intellisense might glitch on .ThenInclude() but error shoud disappear if you spell it right. AuthorizationXref.cs seems correct for including Group

Comment: I forgot about the Intellisense glitch but I still get an error on reference for some reason. even though ICollection<Groups> Group is in AuthorizationXref

Comment: Yeah, I guess I am missing something. This doesn't let me run it for build errors. Which is odd because if I start at the AuthorizationXref level it references perfectly.

Comment: This gets me a bit closer... but the distinct count is wrong.

.Where(x=>x.AuthorizationXref.Select(x=>x.Group.UsersGroupsXref.Select(x=>x.UserId==id)).Any()

Comment: @Slagmoth Oh, I see, I misunderstood your first comment, I thought it's about including but it was about where expression. My bad sorry about that. Maybe try this one Where(x=>x.AuthorizationXref.Any(y=>y.Group.UsersGroupsXref.Any(z=>z.UserId==id))

Comment: Well, it was about best way to do it and the filter. But also a bit about performance. I thought I had tried the .Any before but apparently not. It gives me the correct count now and runs at about ~75ms which is a huge improvement. Thank you. I will just have to verify it gives me the correct 65 reports but appears it should. You may want to incorporate that new where into the answer for posterity.